# UIAlertView didmissWithClickedButtonIndex does not dismiss the alert

Tags: iphone, uialertview

From my object that handles the web service connection, when the network fails, I pass an alert to the view controller that uses the web service object.

WebServiceObject:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed!  You must be connected to a Wifi source to download data.  Please reconnect to a Wifi source and try again later."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    NSDictionary *alertDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:alert, @"AlertView", nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DisplayAlertNotification object:self userInfo:alertDict];
```

ViewController:

```
- (void)displayAlert:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"AlertView"] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [dict objectForKey:@"AlertView"];
                NSNumber *theTag = [dict objectForKey:@"AlertTag"];
    NSLog(@"%i", [theTag integerValue]);
    alert.tag = [[dict objectForKey:@"AlertTag"] integerValue];
        [alert show];
    }
}


- (void)removeAlert:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"AlertTag"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSNumber *theTag = [dict objectForKey:@"AlertTag"];
        UIAlertView *alert = (UIAlertView *)[self.view viewWithTag:[theTag integerValue]];
        // Not sure why but my alert is nil at this point
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I also use the removeAlert method in the same way to remove the alert programmatically.  The goal of this is so if the network failed, but the user didn't click Ok yet, and then the network came back on, I would dismiss the Network Failed alert, and show the Network Resumed alert.  It works except after it dismisses the alert and shows the Network Resumed, once the user clicks Ok on the Network Resumed, the original Network Failed comes back up just once.  If the user clicked Ok while the Network Failed was presented, it never comes back up.

Am I dismissing the alert correctly this way?  Thanks.

Edit: I can get it to work by just saving a reference in the WebServiceObject and dismissing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

you set the alert to nil,  so it do nothing

```
alert = nil;

[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: You are correct in the nil part.  I added that later because the alert was still showing and I added that in the wrong place.  Even without it, it still doesn't make the alert disappear.

Comment: so the problem may be you did not get the right "alert" , "viewWithTag" may return nil ,  just check it

Comment: why don't you just get the "alert" by [dict objectForKey:@"AlertView"] in removeAlert? maybe you should set "alert" as a member variable